# How to reduce worklight application url to shorter form?

Tags: url, ibm-mobilefirst

How to reduce **Worklight** application url?

For ex: My application url is     `//hostname:ipaddress/projectName/apps/services/preview/projectNameApp/common/0/default/projectNameApp.html"`

How to reduce this url to shorter form?

I want to set up a url which can be accessible easily over the internet.
what are the settings required to get shorter url in worklight project

For ex

//hostname:portno/context path/appIndexPage.html

instead of

//hostname:ipaddress/projectName/apps/services/preview/projectNameApp/common/0/default/projectNameApp.html"

Thanks.

Comment: if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 1):

May I know the purpose? These URLs are not meant for public (end-user) consumption; they are internal.

However,

- If you are aiming to use the Mobile Web environment, meaning you take the public URL of the app from Worklight Console and place it in your mobile web site for users to access, [there is the option to use bit.ly to shorten the URL](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/r_miscellaneous_settings.html); you will first need to create an account at http://bit.ly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the URL of your all. This is the URL of the app PREVIEW. Moreover, this is preview of common environment. If you're targeting mobile/desktop web environment - add it to your project and then use WL console to generate short link.