# How to reduce Worklight application url?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

How to reduce below worklight application url to shorter form?

For ex: My application url is //hostname:ipaddress/projectName/apps/services/preview/projectNameApp/common/0/default/projectNameApp.html"

I want to set up a url which can be accessible easily over the internet. what are the settings required to get shorter url in worklight project

For ex

//hostname:portno/context path/appIndexPage.html

instead of

//hostname:ipaddress/projectName/apps/services/preview/projectNameApp/common/0/default/projectNameApp.html"

Thanks.

Comment: I have added mobile web environment and when i click on get app url i got below url.It is bit shorter than preview url. 

hostname:portname/contextroot/apps/services/www/projectname/mobilewebapp/

Can we add customized application url(bit shorter than above url?)is it possible to get shorter url?

Comment: Why do you ask this question again? This is a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reduce worklight application url to shorter form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655949/how-to-reduce-worklight-application-url-to-shorter-form)

Comment: I Just added reply to the answer.I have implemented like above.My question is,is it possible to get shorter app url than above?

Comment: You were already given an answer. For the Mobile Web URL, there is integration with the bit.ly service, that will produdce a shorter URL for you. Please read the answers you are given. For the rest of the URLs, no. Those are also URLs you SHOULD NOT USE IN PUBLIC BECAUSE THEY ARE USED FOR PREVIEW ONLY.

Answer (score 1):

See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18659590/186909) and the getting started module [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/03_12_General_information_when_developing_Mobile_Web_applications.pdf).

*This is not the URL of your all. This is the URL of the app PREVIEW. Moreover, this is preview of common environment. If you're targeting mobile/desktop web environment - add it to your project and then use WL console to generate short link.* - Anton

*If you are aiming to use the Mobile Web environment, meaning you take the public URL of the app from Worklight Console and place it in your mobile web site for users to access, there is the option to use bit.ly to shorten the URL; you will first need to create an account at http://bit.ly.* - Idan Adar

Comment: I have added mobile web environment and when i click on get app url i got below url.It is bit shorter than preview url.

http://hostname:portname/contextroot/apps/services/www/projectname/mobilewebapp/


Can we add customized application url(bit shorter than above url?)is it possible to get shorter url?

Comment: Please read cnandreu's answer again, it mentions that you can use the bit.ly service. You need to create an account there and then use the provided username, password and apikey in worklight.properties. See the following Information Center article: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Fr_ibm_worklight_properties.html

Comment: Is there any alternative solution to get shorter app url apart from http://bit.ly url.

Comment: [URL redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection), [URL shortening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening)